# How can i store angular.forEach to table?

Tags: angularjs

How can i store angular.forEach result to each table row?
I tried to pupulate my table using ng-repeat, but somehow angular-foreach overrides the table row for every loop.

Can someone help me.

Here's a sample of my code

```
$scope.getProfile= function(){

$http({
  method: 'post',
  url: 'url',
  data: some_param,
  headers: {
     'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'
  }
}).then(function(result) {
  $scope.name= result.data.name;
  angular.forEach($scope.name,$scope.getFamily); 
});
}
```

result = {"name":[{"mom_name":"Jane","child_name":["Joey","Jade","Joe","Jenny"],"child_count":4},{"mom_name":"Diane","child_name":["Donny","Daisy","Diana","Douglas","Damon"],"child_count":5},{"mom_name":"Anna","child_name":["Arthur","Amanda","Amon"],"child_count":3}]}

sample for the first forEach loop with mom_name = "Jane"

```
$scope.getFamily = function(name) {
var child_name= name.child_name;
var mom_name= name.mom_name;
$http({
  method: 'post',
  url: 'url',
  data: some_param
  })),
  headers: {
     'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'
  }
}).then(function(result) {
  var name_data = result.data;

  //get gender count
  var total = { mom: mom_name, male: 0, female: 0, female_name: []}; 
  
  for(var i  = 0; i < name_data.length; i++) {
    if(name_data[i]['gender'] == 'male'){
      total['male']++;   
    }
  }
  for(var i  = 0; i < name_data.length; i++) {
    if(name_data[i]['gender'] == 'female'){
      total['female']++;  
      total['female_name'].push(name_data[i]['child_name']);
    }
  }
  $scope.getChildAge(total);


});
```

}

result = [{"child_name":"Joey","gender":"female"},{"child_name":"Jade","gender":"female"},{"child_name":"Jonny","gender":"male"},{"child_name":"John","gender":"male"}]

total = {mom: 'Jane', male: 1, female: 2, female_name: ["Joey","Jade","Jenny"]}

```
$scope.getChildAge= function(data) {

var mom= data.mom;
var female_total= data.female;
var female_name= data.female_name;

$http({
  method: 'post',
  url: 'url',
  data: 
    data: some_param,
  headers: {
     'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'
  }
}).then(function(result) {
  var child_age = result.data;

  var count_num = 0;
  for(var i  = 0; i < child_age.length; i++) {
    if(children[i] > 5){
      count_num++;   
    }
  }
  console.log(count_num);

});
}
```

**I want my output table to be like this**

[desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GzUN.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked my way in getting my desired output

I declare this outside getFamily() function

```
$scope.gender_summary = [];
```

and add this line inside the getFamily()

```
$scope.gender_summary.push(total);
```

then i use the ng-repeat $scope.gender_summary in my table.